# Create new log file on daily basis

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j and want to append application logs in a new file on a daily basis. I am using the following log4j settings but it somehow creates a log file after every hour. Can someone suggest a correct setting to the file which will create a log file at a new date not by hour.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.File=${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss sss} [%p] (%c:%L) %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

instead of

```
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
```